# c# ip address generator to SQL

Tags: c#, python, sql, t-sql

I have the following python code I found on the internet, I would like to make a table in a SQL database with every ipv4 address that there is. I dont code in python but its what I found.

My question is 
1: Is there T-SQL code I can use to generate the table ? (one column ie 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255)

2: Is how would I make this in c#? using the fastest method possible ? I know showing the results slows the console application down by 400 %

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def generate_every_ip_address():
    for octet_1 in range( 256 ):
    for octet_2 in range( 256 ):
    for octet_3 in range( 256 ):
    for octet_4 in range( 256 ):
        yield "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (octet_1, octet_2, octet_3, octet_4)

for ip_address in generate_every_ip_address():
    print ip_address
```

Comment: So that's 4,228,250,625 rows. And you are storing as `varchar(15)`? That will probably take about 100 GB. why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have the space ;) Its a "small" ip address project I am working on

Comment: int oct1 = 0;
            int oct2 = 0;
            int oct3 = 0;
            int oct4 = 0;

'code' while (oct4 < 255)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oct4);
    Console.Write(".");
    Console.Write(oct3);
    Console.Write(".");
    Console.Write(oct2);
                Console.Write(".");
                Console.Write(oct1);

                oct4 = oct4 + 1;
                while (oct3 < 255)
                {
                   oct3 = oct3 + 1;

                   while (oct2 < 255)
{
                       oct2 = oct2 + 1;
                       while (oct1 < 255)
'code'

Comment: Still no idea of the use case for this but main issue is going to be batch size. Doing 4 billion individual transactions will be painful but also you probably don't want to do it in a single transaction either as the T-Log will grow massively (hundreds of GB)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
DECLARE @a INTEGER
DECLARE @b INTEGER
DECLARE @c INTEGER
DECLARE @d INTEGER
DECLARE @IPADDRESS nvarchar(50)

set @a = 0

WHILE @a < 256
BEGIN
    SET @b = 0
    WHILE @b < 256
    BEGIN
        SET @c = 0
        WHILE @c < 256
        BEGIN
            SET @d = 0
            WHILE @d < 256
            BEGIN
                SET @IPADDRESS = CAST(@a AS nvarchar(3)) + '.' + CAST(@b AS nvarchar(3)) + '.' + CAST(@c AS nvarchar(3)) + '.' + CAST(@d AS nvarchar(3))
                PRINT @IPADDRESS
                SET @d = @d + 1
            END
            SET @c = @c + 1
        END
        SET @b = @b + 1
    END
    SET @a = @a + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert in batches of 16,581,375 rows would be quite straightforward using the following TSQL.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 0
SET NOCOUNT ON ;

WHILE ( @Counter <= 255 ) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Procesing %d' ,0,1,@Counter) WITH NOWAIT ;

        WITH    Numbers ( N )
                  AS ( SELECT   CAST(number AS VARCHAR(3))
                       FROM     master.dbo.spt_values
                       WHERE    type = 'P'
                                AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 255
                     )
            INSERT  INTO YourTable
                    ( IPAddress
                    )
                    SELECT  @Counter + '.' + N1.N + '.' + N2.N + '.' + N3.N
                    FROM    Numbers N1 ,
                            Numbers N2 ,
                            Numbers N3 


        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please just use an int IDENTITY column to store each IP address.  They're only 32 bits.  Fill your table up with whatever else you're storing.